# State restoration not work on iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, controller, state-restoration

State restoration does not work well on iOS8.3, same code works well on iOS8.2. This problem can be reproduced by using [apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StateRestoreChildViews/Introduction/Intro.html).

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Launch app and browse to second tab
2. Kill app
3. Launch app again

Expected Results:

> It should return to second tab as restoration result

Actual Results:

> It returns to first tab, which is caused by
>   "application:shouldRestoreApplicationState" has never been called.

Version:

> iOS 8.3 12F69

Notes:

Configuration:

> iPhone Simulator, iPhone 6P

---

Have anyone met similar issue?  Is there a way to workaround it?.

Comment: According Apple's Readme inside the sample's archive, you shouldn't use simulator's multitasking bar to kill the app. Instead you should use Xcode or programmatically call exit. But for me it didn't help anyway, and it doesn't work even on iOS7.1 for some reason.